# JQuery UISlider with multiple DIV as values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have been searching for UI Slider that would change multiple DIV values but couldn't find one which is even close to what I want. I have no technical capability to start it from scratch. Could someone help?

This image depicts what I'm looking for. A multiple DIV changes as the user slides along.
[image: UI Slider]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via jQuery's slider by coding your own slider function.  In this example, at 50% the the text changes.  You can adjust positioning based on value, if need be.

```js
$(function() {
    $(".sli3").slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 50,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.value<50) {
               $(".div-1").text("yay");
               $(".div-2").text("whoo");
            } else {
               $(".div-1").text("example text 1");
               $(".div-2").text("example text 2");
            }
            $(".div-1").css({top:ui.value + "%"})
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.div-1 {
  position:fixed;
  top:50px;
  left:200px;
}

.div-2 {
  position:fixed;
  top:100px;
  left:40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="sli3"></div>

<div class="div-1"></div>
<div class="div-2"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the heads up. I created a JSFiddle based on your code. I would like to add more values but I'm unable to do so. Where am I going wrong? Also, in the JS code, what is line 20 for? I've commented it here:  https://jsfiddle.net/gr68e514/

Comment: UPDATE: I could manage to put a range but I'm unable to get the values to show below 20. The line number between Line 8-11 isn't working: https://jsfiddle.net/zombhbsp/1/

Comment: @ElaineByene https://jsfiddle.net/zombhbsp/4/ updated it with an else-if.  line 20 was to demonstrate that you could move positions with a slider.

Comment: A couple of quick queries on this; a) how do I add a fading effect? b) how do I enable html content? and c) how do I show the first value <=20 by default? https://jsfiddle.net/zombhbsp/5/  I'm marking this as correct. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: change the functions to `.html` instead of `.text`.